# jquery get id of table closest to key press

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating tables on button click and that works great. I then have have a hotkey to add extra rows to those tables. I need to get the parent id of the table where the cursor is but it keeps giving me undefined. I can get the parent div id ok but when I put table in it gives me undefined. Any help would be appreciated

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#divNarrative1").keypress(function(e){    
        alert(e.target.id);
        var msgId = $( this ).closest( 'table' ).attr( 'id' );
        alert(msgId);
    });

});
```

Comment: Does it say the table is undefined (`$( this ).closest( 'table' ) is undefined`) or is the id undefined (`msgId is undefined`)? And what is your HTML?

Comment: Please give us some markup to look at...

Comment: What does the HTML look like? My guess is that #divNarrative1 isn't inside the table so `closest` isn't the appropriate way to traverse the DOM.

Comment: Sorry I added the code but it appears to have added it as an answer? First time posting on here... I changed this to e.target as suggested and still get undefined in my alert of  var msgId = $( e.target ).closest( 'table' ).attr( 'id' );
                     alert(msgId);

Comment: Ryan P is says undefined in the alert not on the page. thanks

Comment: I wrapped the div in a table and it gets that id... so even though the table is inside the div it does not find it...? any ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the `table` is inside `divNarrative1`. In the `keypress` `this` will point to `divNarrative1` and calling `closest` on it will not give you the required `table`. You should use `e.target` instead of `this`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#divNarrative1").keypress(function(e){    
        alert(e.target.id);
        var msgId = $(e.target).closest('table').attr('id');
        alert(msgId);
    });

});
```

**Update:** By OP

Heres the js that creates the table

```
     // Insert HTML table 
function InsertTable() {
     var div = document.getElementById('divNarrative1'); // table reference 

    div.focus();

    document.getElementById("hfProjectBoxNumber").value = Number(document.getElementById("hfProjectBoxNumber").value)+ 1;
    document.getElementById("hfBillTextNumber").value = Number(document.getElementById("hfBillTextNumber").value)+ 1;

    var projdiv = "Projectbox" + document.getElementById("hfProjectBoxNumber").value

     //create table
     var tbl = document.createElement('table');
     tbl.id = projdiv;
     tbl.width = "570px";
     tbl.setAttribute("table-layout", "fixed");
     tbl.setAttribute("border", "1");
     tbl.setAttribute("height", "50px");
     tbl.border = 1;

     //create header row
     var oRow = tbl.insertRow(-1);
     var oCell = oRow.insertCell(-1);
     oCell.width = "570px";
     oCell.setAttribute("colspan", "2");
     oCell.setAttribute("align", "center");
     oCell.innerHTML = projdiv;

     //create coumns
     var oRow = tbl.insertRow(-1);
     var oCell = oRow.insertCell(-1);
     oCell.width = "430px";
     oCell.innerHTML = "DESCRIPTION";
     oCell.setAttribute("align", "center");

     var oCell2 = oRow.insertCell(-1);
     oCell2.width = "140px";
     oCell2.innerHTML = "AMOUNT";
     oCell.setAttribute("align", "center");
     div.appendChild(tbl);
     return false;
 }
```

Heres the html on the page

```
    </div>
        <asp:Button ID="btnEditNarr" runat="server" Text="Edit Narrative" />
        <input type="button" value="Clear all Content" onclick="clearBilltextbox();"/>
        <input type="button" value="Save Content" onclick="getallcontent();"/>

</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: Heres the js that creates the table on button click

Comment: Looking at your update it is clear the `table` is inside the `div` so my answer is correct. Try it.

Comment: even though I am doing this... div.appendChild(tbl); it does not see the table inside the div... if I wrap the div in a table it will find it...

Comment: What is `divNarrative1`? Isn't it a `div` element?

Comment: very baffling... no matter what I do it will not find the table inside the div. Even when I write out the divNarrative1 innerhtml I see the table

Comment: Here is the innerhtml of the div right after the alert undefined comes up...---------------------------
Message from webpage
---------------------------
<TABLE id=projectbox1 border=1 width="100%">

<TBODY>

<TR>

<TH>Description</TH>

<TH>Amount</TH>

<TR>

<TD width=75></TD>

<TD></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE><BR><BR>
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Comment: That looks strange. Can you check what is `e.target` giving?

Comment: But my cursor is inside the table... shouldn't it get the htmltablelement?

Comment: Set the `tabindex` attribute with `-1` value to `table` element so that it will get the focus when you click on it.

Comment: that did not make a difference :(

Comment: <TABLE id=projectbox2 tabIndex=-1 border=1 width="100%">

<TBODY>

<TR>

<TH>Description</TH>

<TH>Amount</TH>

<TR>

<TD width=75></TD>

<TD></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE><BR><BR>

Comment: How do you place the cursor inside the `table`? I don't see any `input` element in the `table`?

Comment: just be clicking in it.... I then type a letter to queue the js function... do I need to put text boxes or something in it?

Comment: ok I added textboxes to the table and it got focus but you have to double click in the text box to add anything and it puts theses selector bars around the text box... anything I can do to get rid of that or is there another element I can put there to fix that? Thanks

Comment: By adding `tabindex` it should work fine. Take a look here I created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ShankarSangoli/57xLR/

Comment: That does not work for me but you did help me figure out why its doing what its doing so thanks! I will mark the answer.